# Backquote in Common Lisp: read and eval

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp, reader-macro

This question is somewhat replated to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575993/how-can-i-reimplement-backquote-in-common-lisp) and [this for Elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807645/in-elisp-how-do-i-apply-backquote-to-lists-read-from-files). Basically, how is the back-quote read and evaluated? What processes are happening? And does the standard say anything about it?

Here is what I would expect, but **it doesn't happen**: symbol ` is a reader-macro and is translated into some kind of `(BACKQUOTE ...)` macro/special form (similarly to `'` being translated to `(QUOTE ...)`). This doesn't happen, and, in fact, Common Lisp doesn't even have a `BACKQUOTE` macro.

What is happening (SBCL):

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *q* (read-from-string "`(a b ,c)"))
*Q*
CL-USER> *q*
`(A B ,C)
CL-USER> (car *q*)
SB-INT:QUASIQUOTE
CL-USER> (cdr *q*)
((A B ,C))
```

Something different from expected, but OK. Now, `,C` is an interesting beast on its own:

```
CL-USER> (type-of (third (cadr *q*)))
SB-IMPL::COMMA
```

If there are no comma-symbols, evaluating the read expression is fine:

```
CL-USER> (eval (read-from-string "`(a b c)"))
(A B C)
```

But if I want to evaluate the original expression even with local binding for `C`, there is a problem:

```
(let ((c 10)) (eval (read-from-string "`(a b ,c)")))
; in: LET ((C 10))
;     (LET ((C 10))
;       (EVAL (READ-FROM-STRING "`(a b ,c)")))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable C is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE C {1007A3B2F3}>.
```

This means that `EVAL` didn't pick up the environment in which `C` is bound.

PS. Interestingly enough, in Elisp this works.

Comment: @RainerJoswig are "standard macro character" and "reader macro" the same thing or am I confused about them?

Comment: 'standard macro character' means that a character is a macro character defined by the standard. The CLHS glossary: macro character n. a character which, when encountered by the Lisp reader in its main dispatch loop, introduces a reader macro.

Comment: For technical details you can also look at how your implementation manipulates quasiquotes as welll as [Faré quasiquotes](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/frideau/fare-quasiquote).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Backquote**

[Backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) is a standard [macro character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_m.htm#macro_character) in Common Lisp.

In Common Lisp the representation of a backquote expression is undefined. Implementations actually use different representations. What you see for SBCL is implementation specific.

**EVAL**

The problem you have with [eval](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm#eval) is fully unrelated to the reader or backquote expressions:

```
? (let ((c 10))
    (eval '(list 'a 'b c)))

Error: The variable C is unbound.
```

In Common Lisp `EVAL` is using the dynamic environment and the [null lexical environment](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_n.htm#null_lexical_environment) for evaluation of forms. Above lexical environment, where `c` is bound to `10`, is not used.

But the dynamic binding is. We need to declare the variable to be  `special`:

```
? (let ((c 10))
    (declare (special c))
    (eval '(list 'a 'b c)))
(A B 10)
```

Thus this works, too:

```
? (let ((c 10))
    (declare (special c))
    (eval (read-from-string "`(a b ,c)")))
(A B 10)
```

Emacs Lisp had/has dynamic binding by default (though GNU Emacs now also supports lexical binding). Common Lisp has lexical binding by default.

Comment: I didn't know about `EVAL` using null lexical environment. Thanks!